# How to check if token has expired

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to write a simple OAuth2 client based on oauth2 gem. The idea is to store an access token in a session and check if it's not expired before every request.

The following code for getting a new token looks like that:

```
client = OAuth2::Client.new(
  '26b8e5c92367d703ad35a2fc16b14dc93327a15798068ccba473aa2e3d897883',
  'b16079915cdc20b5373f1601e31cece5a84274f772cfd89aec12c90fd110775e',
  site: 'http://localhost:3000'
)

client.client_credentials.get_token.expired?
```

and it's working fine. Request to my api is fired and the last line shows if token has expired or not. The problem is when i'm trying to restore token state by myself:

```
OAuth2::AccessToken.new(client, session[:api_token]).expired?
```

This line of code does not fire the request to my api and, in cause of that, has no idea what's that token lifetime, expires_at param or anything else. Everything besides 'token' param is nil so `expired?` method always returns `false`:

```
#<OAuth2::AccessToken:0x007fad4c9e2e28 @client=#<OAuth2::Client:0x007fad4ddb7160 @id="26b8e5c92367d703ad35a2fc16b14dc93327a15798068ccba473aa2e3d897883", @secret="b16079915cdc20b5373f1601e31cece5a84274f772cfd89aec12c90fd110775e", @site="http://localhost:3000", @options={:authorize_url=>"/oauth/authorize", :token_url=>"/oauth/token", :token_method=>:post, :connection_opts=>{}, :connection_build=>nil, :max_redirects=>5, :raise_errors=>true}, @client_credentials=#<OAuth2::Strategy::ClientCredentials:0x007fad4ddb6f80 @client=#<OAuth2::Client:0x007fad4ddb7160 ...>>, @connection=#<Faraday::Connection:0x007fad4ddb6738 @headers={"User-Agent"=>"Faraday v0.8.8"}, @params={}, @options={}, @ssl={}, @parallel_manager=nil, @default_parallel_manager=nil, @builder=#<Faraday::Builder:0x007fad4ddb6620 @handlers=[Faraday::Request::UrlEncoded, Faraday::Adapter::NetHttp]>, @url_prefix=#<URI::HTTP:0x007fad4ddb60d0 URL:http://localhost:3000/>, @proxy=nil, @app=#<Faraday::Request::UrlEncoded:0x007fad4ddb4190 @app=#<Faraday::Adapter::NetHttp:0x007fad4ddb4280 @app=#<Proc:0x007fad4ddb4370@/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/faraday-0.8.8/lib/faraday/connection.rb:93 (lambda)>>>>>, @token="114781bdace77fa7f4629e2b42dbe68ac73326728dddc8102b9c2269e3e86a36", @refresh_token=nil, @expires_in=nil, @expires_at=nil, @options={:mode=>:header, :header_format=>"Bearer %s", :param_name=>"access_token"}, @params={}>
```

Am i doing something wrong or is that some kind of a bug? To sum it all up: i need to check if token stored in a session (as a string) has expired or not.

Comment: Does your code reach that line?

Comment: And does it give an error? What exactly is the result?

Comment: Nope, no errors. Please have a look at the original question, i have added that.

Comment: check the value you put in session, is it the right token?

Comment: yes, that's definitely a good one

Comment: Did you mean to use OAuth2::AccessToken.initialize ?
[link](http://rdoc.info/github/intridea/oauth2/OAuth2/AccessToken:initialize)

Comment: i can't use that cause there is a required `client` param which i don't have. I need to check if the token has expired using only the token itself.

Answer (score 3):

If you check the code of AccessToken, you have to pass a third parameter (options) containing "expires_at" value which is used when you are calling expired? :

```
def initialize(client, token, opts={})
  @client = client
  @token = token.to_s
  [:refresh_token, :expires_in, :expires_at].each do |arg|
    instance_variable_set("@#{arg}", opts.delete(arg) || opts.delete(arg.to_s))
  end
  @expires_in ||= opts.delete('expires')
  @expires_in &&= @expires_in.to_i
  @expires_at &&= @expires_at.to_i
  @expires_at ||= Time.now.to_i + @expires_in if @expires_in
  @options = {:mode          => opts.delete(:mode) || :header,
              :header_format => opts.delete(:header_format) || 'Bearer %s',
              :param_name    => opts.delete(:param_name) || 'access_token'}
  @params = opts
end

...

def expired?
  expires? && (expires_at < Time.now.to_i)
end
```

source: https://github.com/intridea/oauth2/blob/master/lib/oauth2/access_token.rb#L42

So update your code to something like:

`OAuth2::AccessToken.new(client, session[:api_token], {expires_at: session[:expires_at]}).expired?`

Comment: but 1) the expiration is typically handled on the provider side and 2) resource owners can typically revoke access at any time. we need a graceful way to handle expired/revoked tokens without being able to predict it from the client side.